# How to use rsync properly to keep all file permissions and ownership?

Tags: linux, permissions, backup, rsync, ownership

I am trying to use rsync to backup some data from one computer (PopOS! 21.04) to another (Rocky 8.4). But no matter which flags I use with rsync, file permissions and ownership never seem to be saved.

What I do, is run this command locally on PopOS:
`sudo rsync -avz /home/user1/test/ root@192.168.10.11:/root/ttt/`

And the result I get something link this:

```
[root@rocky_clone0 ~]# ls -ld ttt/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user23 user23 32 Dec 17  2021 ttt/
[root@rocky_clone0 ~]# ls -l ttt/
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user23 user23 57 Dec 17  2021 test1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user23 user23 29 Dec 17  2021 test2
```

So all the file ownership change to user23, which is the only regular user on Rocky. I don't understand how this happens, with rsync I am connecting to root on the remote host, but as the result files are copied as user23. Why isn't -a flag work properly in this case?

I have also tried these flags:
`sudo rsync -avz --rsync-path="sudo -u user23 rsync -a" /home/user1/test root@192.168.10.11:/home/user23/rrr`
This command couldn't copy to the root directory, so I had to change the remote destination to user23's home folder. But the result is the same.

If someone could explain to me what am I doing wrong, and how to backup files with rsync so that permissions and ownership stay the same as on the local computer I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how the (target)filesystem is mounted on the Rocky(target) system.

Some mounted filesystems (such as many FUSE mounts) do not support the classical unix permissions, and simply use the name of the user who mounted the filesystem as owner/group.
Any attempt to chown/chmod/etc (either by you or by rsync) will just silently be ignored, but appear to "succeed" (no errors reported).